# how to print last 3 datas from the maximum date using pandas python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas, dataframe

```
date        sales 
2014-03-13  10000.000 
2014-03-21   2000.000 
2014-03-27   2000.000 
2014-03-17    200.000 
2014-03-17      5.000 
2014-03-17     70.000 
2014-03-21    200.000 
2014-03-27      5.000 
2014-03-27     25.000 
2014-03-31      0.020 
2014-03-31     12.000 
2014-03-31      0.022
```

this is my dataframe. I have to find maxium date in date column and also print last 3 datas from max date.

example:
if 2014-03-31 maximum date means I have to print last datas from max date. I mean (31,30,29 dates data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
#converting column date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

print df
         date      sales
0  2014-03-13  10000.000
1  2014-03-21   2000.000
2  2014-03-27   2000.000
3  2014-03-17    200.000
4  2014-03-17      5.000
5  2014-03-28     70.000
6  2014-03-29    200.000
7  2014-03-29      5.000
8  2014-03-30     25.000
9  2014-03-31      0.020
10 2014-03-31     12.000
11 2014-03-31      0.022

print df[df['date'].isin(pd.date_range(end=df.date.max(), periods=3))]

         date    sales
6  2014-03-29  200.000
7  2014-03-29    5.000
8  2014-03-30   25.000
9  2014-03-31    0.020
10 2014-03-31   12.000
11 2014-03-31    0.022
```

If some `dates` are missing, it is complicated - use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print df
         date      sales
0  2014-03-13  10000.000
1  2014-03-21   2000.000
2  2014-03-27   2000.000
3  2014-03-17    200.000
4  2014-03-17      5.000
5  2014-03-17     70.000
6  2014-03-21    200.000
7  2014-03-27      5.000
8  2014-03-27     25.000
9  2014-03-31      0.020
10 2014-03-31     12.000
11 2014-03-31      0.022

#resample by days and merge to original df, fill NaN to 0 in column sales
df1 = df.set_index('date').resample('D').first().reset_index().drop('sales', axis=1)
df2 = pd.merge(df1, df, on='date', how='left').fillna({'sales': 0})

print df2[df2['date'].isin(pd.date_range(end=df.date.max(), periods=3))]
         date   sales
21 2014-03-29   0.000
22 2014-03-30   0.000
23 2014-03-31   0.020
24 2014-03-31  12.000
25 2014-03-31   0.022
```

Comment: if maximum date 2014-03-31,,i need datas for 31,30,29 date datas

Comment: if i need last 10 datas from max date means?

Comment: Then change parameter `2` in `pd.to_timedelta(2, unit='D')` to `9`.

Comment: in my sample there is no 30,29 dates right?? intead of this date i have to put zero...how can i add?

Comment: Sorry, solution is changed, you need change `3` to `10`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111112/discussion-between-jezrael-and-sai-rajesh).